# DirectShow integrated webcam exposure control

Tags: settings, directshow, webcam, integrated

I'm trying to control the exposure settings in a laptop integrated webcam.

I can't control it programatically through DirectShow -
IAMCameraControl interface returns E_PROP_ID_UNSUPPORTED when I call it with 
CameraControl_Exposure as the CameraControlProperty.

I've successfully changed the exposure settings in different capture devices (such as Logitech webcams) using the above DirectShow interface.

Is there another DirectShow interface that I could use for exposure control when IAMCameraControl can't do so?

Is there any other method in which I could control the exposure settings? maybe directly through the camera driver (without using DirectShow as a mediator), if so - how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When the camera doesn't offer this setting through DirectShow, you are left only with using manufacturer specific interfaces, which are "manufacturer specific".

Have you tried to run the camera in GraphEdit ? That shows a dialog for the properties the device supports.

Comment: I ran it in GraphEdit, and exposure control is indeed Greyed out. So it seems like I can't control it through DirectShow.

How could I access to the manufacturer specific interfaces?
I didn't see any documentation on the integrated webcam's interfaces.. (I'm waiting for a reply in the laptop's support forum)

Comment: There is no way to know. Either the camera manufacturer discloses this information, or you reverse engineer it.